# Where is the google home ble specification?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, assistant

I have searched everywhere but I cannot seem to find what profile or (custom) services are used to connect a ble device to a Google home. like a smart lock or smart lighting for example. Can anyone point me in the right direction? There must be some protocol specification somewhere for ble devices connected to google home?
I am asking specifically about ble, not bluetooth classic.

We are developing a bluetooth 5 enabled device and are looking into the effort it will take to support google home/assistant.

Thank you.